# JsonIncludeProperties with JsonUnwrapped

Tags: java, json, jackson

Can I use these annotation for my class to my expected json?

```
public class Staff {
  private String name;
  private Integer age;
  @JsonUnwrapped
  private Staff manager;

  .... getter and setter ....
}
```

```
{
  "name": "Fanny",
  "age": 24,
  "manager": "Timmy"
}
```

I know I can use JsonIgnoreProperties but I need to unwrap name only. Any solution? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have a getter for the name that returns a String and annotate it with `@JsonPropery`,

Can I use these annotation for my class to my expected json?

```
public class Staff {
  private String name;
  private Integer age;
  @JsonIgnore
  private Staff manager;
  
  @JsonProperty("managerName")
  public String getManagerName() {
      return this.manager.getName();
  }   
  .... getter and setter ....
}
```

Comment: Thanks. It's solved perfectly but I think Jackson support JsonIncludeProperties will be better because it is the opposite of JsonIgnoreProperties.